# sonarqube scanner for plsql files stored with .pak extension not scanning

Tags: plsql, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, plsql-package, sonarscanner

We have stored our PL/SQL files with .sql and .pak (for packages) extensions in bitbucket and we are trying to run sonarqube scanner on these files but the scanner is not taking .pak files into consideration while scanning.

the sonar-project.properties file looks like

```
sonar.projectKey=XYZ
sonar.projectName=XYZ
sonar.projectDescription=PL/SQL Demo
sonar.sources=.
sonar.inclusions=**/sql/*.sql,**/package/*.pak
sonar.language=plsql
```

This is scanning .sql files but not .pak files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by adding below line in the sonar-project.properties file,

sonar.plsql.file.suffixes=sql,pak

In above line, we can add other extensions also if we want to scan code.